# The form of math input in stack exchange

Tags: discussion

[image: why?]

what's the error I got here? why it is wrong? How should I make this right for post?

Comment: Hmm, I don't know. What a useless message.

Comment: However, if you wanted to post the question like this, it would have been closed because this is the site for the **software** Mathematica. Please ask purely math-related questions on [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The problem may have been in the title. Common title problems are too short or already in use by another question. There would have been a floating explanatory message up by the title.

Comment: If the equation $q^n+a_{n-1} q^{n-1} + \cdots + a_0  = 0$ has repeated roots, then you will also have terms containing $t^r$.  Anyway, check out a textbook on ordinary differential equations and/or linear circuit theory.

Comment: LaTeX doesn't work over here?

Comment: @mjw, yes, it's only enabled for the main site, and not the meta site.